# How to re-use my validation logic in other models, and reduce duplicate code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2-3 "form" models that I am verifying that the password is in the correct format etc.

How can I refactor my code so I don't repeat this logic 3 times in my codebase?

```
class ResetPasswordForm
    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

    validates_presence_of :password, presence: true, 
                                                length: { minimum: 8, maximum: 20},
                                                confirmation: true

    #validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 8, :maximum => 64, :allow_blank => false
    validate :password_complexity

    def password_complexity
        unless password.blank?
            errors.add(:password, "must contain a upper case character") unless password.match(/[A-Z]/)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Just create a module and stick that method inside it.  Then include it like you did with ActiveModel::Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Rails5 you'll notice your models now inherit from ApplicationRecord which then inherits from ActiveRecord::Base.  So if on Rails5 you can add your method to ApplicationRecord and then reference it in your before_action in your models.  If on Rails <=4 you can create a new module in your lib folder: `lib/password_complexity.rb`.

```
module PasswordComplexity

  def check_the_password
     password_present?
     password_complexity
  end

  def password_complexity
    unless self.password.blank?
      errors.add(:password, "must contain a upper case character") unless password.match(/[A-Z]/)
    end
  end

  def password_present?
     if self.password.blank? || self.password.length < 8 || self.password.length > 20 || self.password != self.password_confirmation
       errors.add(:password, "some message")
     end #Youll want to change this probably to multiple if's that have specific error messages.
  end
end
```

Then add the line: `include PasswordComplexity` in your models and add:

```
validate :check_the_password
```

to your models.

Note: It's important to follow the naming convention I did so when you reference PasswordComplexity, Rails will search for a file password_complexity.rb

Comment: But I want to also have validates_presence_of, not just the password_complexity method. Possible?

Comment: I think the cleanest way to go in that regard would be to create a module combining both methods (write your own version of the validates_presence_of method) and then use that.  You wont have to access to the validates_presence_of without specifically including that in your module as well which would be messy.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm on rails 4.x

Comment: If I want to put the file in /validations/password_complexity.rb how will that change my include?

Comment: You'll need to add that folder to your Rails load path I think.  I think Rails only loads one level deep in your lib folder so if it gives an error on not finding your module you'll want to add that folder via your config/application.rb file.  Something like config.load_paths << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/validations"